# Jackson serialization not handling single quote properly

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring, jackson

I have just started using Jackson because of the integration with the Spring Framework and have run into an issue with single quotes in a value. When trying to parse the JSON with jQuery on the page, I get a JavaScript error `"SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"`. I am used to using Gson to serialize my objects and don't run into this issue as Gson will replace the single quote with the Unicode \u0027.

For example;
**Java**

```
public final class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public Person() {}

  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
}
```

**JSON**
In Jackson

`[{"person":{"firstName":"James","lastName":"O'tool"}}]`


In Gson

`[{"person":{"firstName":"James","lastName":"O\u0027tool"}}]`

**JavaScript**;

`// This is where the JavaScript fails with the Jackson serialized object

$.parseJSON('${requestScope.person}');`

I have looked for a solution, but am unable to find one.
Does anyone know if it is possible to configure Jackson to handle single quotes the same way Gson does?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do not try to output JSON in string literals (escaping them of course) and parse them. Just output Object Literals!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that this is not an ajax call and the parsing of the JSON object happens on a JSP. If this were a straight-up ajax call, there wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: No, you are trying to parse an (incorrectly escaped) JSON string with JavaScript (not JSP)

Comment: I understand that. Google's Gson library does this by default and I was just wondering if there was some way Jackson could do the same thing.

Comment: A post by Jason about json, talking about jackson and then resolved with some code from Gson. It's to late for my head to understand this ... :)

Comment: Well, when you put it like that I guess it is a little confusing. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answer shows one way to do this, and it should work pretty well.

But there is another way to do this as well, which is bit less work, explained at "[Forcing escaping of HTML characters in JSON using Jackson](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2012/08/entry_476.html)"

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you! I just wish there was a way to register the custom CharacterEscapes in Spring with the Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean class.

Comment: Might be worth suggesting that to Spring dev team?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, I ended up creating a custom String serializer for Jackson. I borrowed some source from Gson.

```
    public class HtmlStringSerializer extends StdSerializer<String> {
      protected HtmlStringSerializer() { super(String.class); }

      private static final String[] HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS;
      static {
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS = new String[128];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 0x1f; i++) {
          HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS[i] = String.format("\\u%04x", i);
        }
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['"'] = "\\\"";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['\\'] = "\\\\";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['\t'] = "\\t";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['\b'] = "\\b";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['\n'] = "\\n";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['\r'] = "\\r";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['\f'] = "\\f";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['<'] = "\\u003c";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['>'] = "\\u003e";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['&'] = "\\u0026";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['='] = "\\u003d";
        HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS['\''] = "\\u0027";
      }

      @Override
      public void serialize(String string, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        int last = 0;
        int length = string.length();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          char c = string.charAt(i);
          String replacement;
          if (c < 128) {
            replacement = HTML_SAFE_REPLACEMENT_CHARS[c];
            if (replacement == null) { continue; }
          } else if (c == '\u2028') {
            replacement = "\\u2028";
          } else if (c == '\u2029') {
            replacement = "\\u2029";
          } else {
            continue;
          }
          if (last < i) {
        sb.append(string.substring(last, i));
          }
          sb.append(replacement);
          last = i + 1;
        }
        if (last < length) {
          sb.append(string.substring(last));
        }
        gen.writeString(sb.toString());
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi was trying to say: don't use:

```
$.parseJSON('${requestScope.person}')
```

simply use

```
${requestScope.person}
```

directly!

Comment: It's funny: You interpreted the comment from the client side, and I interpreted it from the server side. I thought @Bergi was saying to pass objects into Jackson so that it doesn't escape quote chars in a String.